# Write a SQL statement to list the item IDs and item descriptions of items that have never been sold. I am having trouble with the null and joining

Tags: sql, mysql

Here is the database
[DatabaseTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ME8hb.png)
This is what I attempted to do. I am having issues with pulling values and joining the tables. I thought I would only need Sale_ITEM and not Sale

```
SELECT item.itemid, item.itemdescription
FROM item
LEFT JOIN sale_Item ON item.itemid = sale_item.item_id
WHERE sale_item.item_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Can you give me an example of your tables os I know how to properly structure the query ?

Comment: Why are you using underscore in field name? If you want to prevent duplicate combinations of sale and item, then SaleID and ItemID should be compound unique index. Whether or not there is a designated primary key in Sale_Item is not important because no table is dependent on it but SaleItemID could be set as primary key.

Comment: When asking SQL questions, you should provide both sample data and expected result as tables directly in your question, don't link off to external sites.

Comment: @JonasMetzler, imgur images are acceptable for clarification. However, they can be embedded for display in question without having to click to open. Although, in this case it would make the image harder to read. Viewing image did clarify source of issue for me.

Comment: Agree that data as formatted text table(s) and/or DDL SQL can often be helpful. What should also be provided is description of 'issues'. What happens - error message, wrong result, nothing?

Answer (score 0):

In any case, this could be achieved using a subquery.

We can fetch all the items that are not present in the sale_item table.

Let me know if you have questions.

```sql
SELECT item.itemid, item.itemdescription
FROM item
WHERE item.itemid NOT IN (
  SELECT sale_Item.item_id
  FROM sale_Item
);
```

Comment: Actually, a subquery is not needed for this "find unmatched" requirement. The JOIN should work if fields are correctly referenced.

Comment: That's true, I just gave them an alternative approach to their question. Always pays knowing multiple ways to do a single thing

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately your answer does not address the actual issue as evidenced by the ERD image.